Restricting WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 Gateway Root URL access

Accessing Gateway root URL

Is there a way to restrict access to this URL when the gateway is exposed for external use ?. Ideally, the main sequence shouldn't trigger when the root URL is invoked. We could do this from the LB but I was wondering if I can restrict it somehow via APIM

Please post the code as text,  but not screenshot.
